# Lamdas vs Functions in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, mocha.js

Mocha discourages lambda functions in JavaScript, but to my knowledge lambda's in typescript predated JavaScript.

> https://mochajs.org/#arrow-functions
>
> Passing arrow functions (aka "lambdas") to Mocha is discouraged.
>   Lambdas lexically bind this and cannot access the Mocha context. For
>   example, the following code will fail:
>
> ```
> describe('my suite', () => {
>   it('my test', () => {
>     // should set the timeout of this test to 1000 ms; instead will fail
>     this.timeout(1000);
>     assert.ok(true);
>   });
> });
> ```
>
> If you do not need to use Mocha's context, lambdas should work.
>   However, the result will be more difficult to refactor if the need
>   eventually arises.

So this begs the question, Does TypeScripts Lambda's functionality differentiate from JS, in that 'this' is not bound lexically?

Aka Can I use typescript lambda's in Mocha as short form functions?

If not now, have they historically differed?

Comment: Typescript's lambda funcionality is the same as JS. You can use `.bind(this,false/true)` to keep the $scope as the function or the component.

Comment: Has it always been that way historically, or was I incorrect in the assumption that typescript had arrow notation first, or did it just act the same?

Comment: Typescript is supposed to compile to ECMAScript, you can try it in ts playground and check the output code. eg: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?target=2#code/CYUwzgxgTglgRiAFAcgLYE8AEYCuMAuIyANJogJSYC8AfJgN4BQmmBKGmhY+JZltDZi0wB6EdgAWAexwAbYNhD5OEkJxioQM5VIBmKmGE7hl+KZgCMABhuZUYANysAdtxABDBQHcYs2Zl13XyEWfAlDADp8DS0cfERrG3IHEMx3MDAQKHwIqQBrRHwoHBBkoQBfMsqUxiA

Comment: I don't think Typescript had arrow notation before Javascript did. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TypeScript), *"TypeScript adds support for features such as classes, modules, and an arrow function syntax as defined in the ECMAScript 2015 standard."*

Comment: The oldest I can go on the playground is 2.4.1 . Finding documentation on specific typescript versions is difficult. 'fat arrow' was introduced to JS in ES6